Does the True Strike spell's material component requirement conflict with the 2024 UA Artificer's spellcasting requirements?
I have a question about how the True Strike spell interacts with the 2024 UA Artificer's spellcasting mechanics, particularly regarding material component requirements.
Artificer (UA) Spellcasting Mechanics:

You produce your Artificer spells through tools. You can use Thieves’ Tools,  Tinker’s Tools, or another kind of Artisan’s Tools with which you have  proficiency as a Spellcasting Focus, and you must have one of those focuses in hand when you cast an Artificer spell (meaning the spell has an “M” component when you cast it).

The True Strike spell has both a somatic component and material components: S, M (a weapon with which you have proficiency and that is worth 1+ CP. The spell description states:

Guided by magical insight, you make one attack with the weapon used in the spell’s casting. [...]

The issue arises when an Artificer attempts to cast True Strike with a weapon like a Heavy Crossbow or Musket. The spell requires the weapon as the Material (M) component, which would normally not be an issue. However, since Artificers must use their tools as a spellcasting focus, they need a free hand to hold the tools during the spell's casting.
This creates a conflict:

To cast the spell, the Artificer must hold their Tinker’s Tools (or equivalent) in one hand.
To fire the weapon (the Material component), they need two hands.

Narratively, I can imagine the character pulling out a tool from their pouch, "fiddling" with the crossbow or musket to cast the spell and then putting the tool back into the pouch to fire the weapon. However, this would normally require an object interaction to stow the tool, complicating the process.
This issue doesn’t typically come up with spells that have costless Material components, as those can be handled with a Component Pouch or Spellcasting Focus. For example, when casting the Light cantrip (which requires firefly moss), the caster simply accesses the pouch and casts the spell without concern for ongoing interactions.
The rules for Material (M) spell components state:

A Material component is a particular material used in a spell’s
casting, as specified in parentheses in the Components entry. These
materials aren’t consumed by the spell unless the spell’s description
states otherwise. The spellcaster must have a hand free to access
them, but it can be the same hand used to perform Somatic components,
if any.
If a spell doesn’t consume its materials and doesn’t specify a cost
for them, a spellcaster can use a Component Pouch (see chapter 6)
instead of providing the materials specified in the spell, or the
spellcaster can substitute a Spellcasting Focus if the caster has a
feature that allows that substitution. To use a Component Pouch, you
must have a hand free to reach into it, and to use a Spellcasting
Focus, you must hold it unless its description says otherwise (see
chapter 6 for descriptions).

This makes me think that the Artificer's Tools fall under this rule in a similar fashion and no longer fall under the utilize or object interaction rules normally associated with tools or items.
A couple of related questions with regards to the True Strike cantrip arise from these various rules:

Are Artificers allowed to briefly use their tools to cast True Strike and then stow them to attack with the weapon as part of the spell?
Are Artificers effectively prevented from using True Strike with two-handed weapons due to their need to hold the tools throughout the spellcasting process?
Would the same restriction apply to an Artificer using a Hand Crossbow, as they would also need a free hand to load the weapon?


I think the question in the title is fine, but the text is way to broad. This site is not a site for discussions, but for succinct questions and answers.

I don't really agree with the close reasons for this question as I think you've done a great job showing your research to back up your question and I think the questions you've asked are all closely related to justify keeping in the same question. I have made some minor edits to just remove things wherein you are requesting opinions, but they were overall minor. Please ensure I did not change your intent.

@JoakimM.H. the site is for questions and answers, but it's not necessary for them to be succinct. Sometimes to ask a proper question, you're going to need 1000 words and the answer will be 10 words; other times the reverse is true. One of the most key things for SE is that querents have at least attempted to solve the problem for themselves and thus provide their own research with their question. This querent has done that.

@Pyrotechnical succinct might not be the correct word; I'm not a native English speaker. What I meant was precise and well defined.

I think the 3 questions are basically just asking around the edges of the central question of how these 2 rules interact – though I might argue that #3 is worth editing out and asking as a separate question (since it's about the Loading weapon property rather than the Two-Handed one), depending on the consensus for this question. (The question does suffer from a little over-quoting and/or meandering, but that's a solvable problem.)

An artificer has additional spellcasting restrictions that others do not
The UA rules as written (and this may be something worth commenting on in the applicable survey) impose requirements on artificers that other casters do not have.
For example, the following language regarding spellcasting foci for the following classes:

Bard: "Spellcasting Focus. You can use a Musical Instrument as a Spellcasting Focus for your Bard spells."
Cleric: "Spellcasting Focus. You can use a Holy Symbol as a Spellcasting Focus for your Cleric spells."
Druid: "Spellcasting Focus. You can use a Druidic Focus as a Spellcasting Focus for your Druid spells."
Paladin: "Spellcasting Focus. You can use a Holy Symbol as a Spellcasting Focus for your Paladin spells."

...I'm not going to list them all, but in short, there's a pattern and it's that the character has a choice.
However, the choice of language in the UA for the new Artificer deviates in the substantial way you've identified:

Tools Required. You produce your Artificer spells through tools. You can use Thieves’ Tools, Tinker’s Tools, or another kind of Artisan’s Tools with which you have proficiency as a Spellcasting Focus, and you must have one of those focuses in hand when you cast an Artificer spell (meaning the spell has an “M” component when you cast it).

The language used wasn't that you can use the tools as a focus, rather you must. Which means that unlike other casters, Artificers cannot utilize the specific material components referenced in spell descriptions, rather they must use their tools.
Therefore, to answer your questions:
1. Should the Artificer be allowed to briefly use their tools to cast True Strike and then stow them to fire the weapon as part of the spell?
This is a DM decision, and even RAW the answer isn't totally clear (see these questions about dropping weapons and dropping objects).
2. Are Artificers effectively prevented from using True Strike with two-handed weapons due to their need to hold the tools throughout the spellcasting process?
As I cannot see a way for them to satisfy the requirements of the weapon along with their own unique spellcasting requirement, it seems they are unable to cast True Strike with a two-handed weapon.
3. Would the same restriction apply to an Artificer using a hand crossbow, as they would also need a free hand to load the weapon?
Not if the weapon was already loaded and you were simply making one shot with it.

There is no conflict
The UA2024 Artificer states, in part, emphasis mine:

You   CAN use Thieves’ Tools, Tinker’s Tools, or another kind of
Artisan’s Tools   with which you have proficiency as a Spellcasting
Focus...

This indicates that the Artificer has the option to use his/her tools as spellcasting foci, provided all other spellcasting requirements/restrictions are met.  The description goes on to say

and   you must have one of those focuses in hand when you cast
an Artificer spell

The sentence seems to contradict itself with the second clause.
If I had to guess
I would assume that the second clause clarifies that if you are using one of the tools mentioned, then you must have it in hand.
Furthermore...
The description of using material components changed in the UA2024 edition from the original Ebberon statement, which stated in part

You produce your artificer spell effects through your tools. You must
have a spellcasting focus—specifically thieves' tools or some kind of
artisan's tool—in hand when you cast any spell with this Spellcasting
feature...

In this situation, the Artificer is still required to use their weapon as a spellcasting focus.

The answer to this turns out to be surprisingly poorly defined, at least in certain edge cases. Fortunately, the specific cases being asked about here don't fall into those edge cases.
Casting True Strike only requires one hand
Let's look at this sentence from the PHB rules on material components:

The spellcaster must have a hand free to access [the spell's material components], but it can be the same hand used to perform Somatic components, if any.

The important point here is that even if a spell requires multiple material components, you can still cast the spell with one hand. In the case of the artificer, True Strike requires 2 material components: the weapon and the artificer's spellcasting focus. The artificer can manipulate both of these components with the same hand when they cast the spell.
With this in mind, let's see how this applies to the 3 sub-questions presented at the end of the question:
1. No rule enables an extra free object interaction for stowing/retrieving the focus
To answer your question 1: As far as I know, there are no explicit or implied rules that allow an extra free object interaction for the artificer to pull out their tools before casting a spell and then stow them afterward. So we're going to have to figure something out without that. (See the end of the answer for more on this.)
2. You can make a two-handed attack as part of the spell
The rules for two-handed weapons say:

A Two-Handed weapon requires two hands when you attack with it.

Fortunately, it is fairly easy to accomplish this while casting True Strike. Since the rules for material components allow you to manipulate all the material components with one hand, you can simply put your second hand on the weapon and make the two-handed attack, thus fulfilling the requirements of both the spell's material components and the two-handed weapon property.
3. You can make an attack with an ammunition weapon as part of the spell
The rules for ammunition say:

Drawing the ammunition is part of the attack (you need a free hand to load a one-handed weapon).

We can apply the same principle here as with the two-handed property: your first hand can manipulate both the weapon and the focus, while your second hand is free to draw the weapon's ammunition (and also hold the weapon, if it has both the two-handed and ammunition properties).
What about before and after casting the spell?
The above is all well and good, mainly because the rules for material components allow the player to manipulate both the weapon and the focus with the same hand while casting a spell. However, what do the rules have to say about how you manipulate these two objects on the rest of your turn? Ironically, the two-handed cases asked about in this question are actually easier to answer, since you can simply transfer the focus to your free hand when you're not casting with it. This is possible because two-handed and ammunition weapons both only require a second hand on the weapon while making an attack with it.
However, let's pose a more difficult situation: what if the artificer wants to cast True Strike with their perfectly normal one-handed handaxe while their second hand is occupied with something else? Perhaps they are wielding a shield in their other hand, or perhaps they have just grabbed the Macguffin of Ultimate Power and they really don't want to put it down just to make their attack. What do the rules have to say on this?
An aside to define "equip"
Unfortunately, it seems that the rules on equipping weapons and items are a bit vague. For example, as far as I can tell, there's nothing in the rules saying you can only attack with weapons you have equipped. Take the description of the attack action in the rules glossary:

Attack [Action]
When you take the Attack action, you can make one attack roll with a weapon or an Unarmed Strike.
Equipping and Unequipping Weapons. You can either equip or unequip one weapon when you make an attack as part of this action. You do so either before or after the attack. If you equip a weapon before an attack, you don’t need to use it for that attack. Equipping a weapon includes drawing it from a sheath or picking it up. Unequipping a weapon includes sheathing, stowing, or dropping it.
Moving between Attacks. If you move on your turn and have a feature, such as Extra Attack, that gives you more than one attack as part of the Attack action, you can use some or all of that movement to move between those attacks.

Ok, so we have instructions for equipping weapons. But... nothing saying what equipping the weapon actually does or specifically stating that it is required in order to make an attack with that weapon. So, we can refer to the dictionary definition of "equip": "to make ready". Applying this, we conclude that a weapon must be equipped before it is ready to be used for making attacks. (However, note that the rules for equipping/unequipping during the Attack action will not come into play directly with True Strike, since we are not using the Attack action, we are casting a spell with the Magic action.) For melee weapons in particular, we have some more specific guidance in the section on melee attacks that weapons are handheld:

A melee attack typically uses a handheld weapon or an Unarmed Strike.

There is also a section in the Equipment chapter on wearing and wielding items:

Using a magic item’s properties might mean wearing or wielding it. A magic item meant to be worn must be donned in the intended fashion: boots go on feet, gloves on hands, hats and helmets on a head, and rings on a finger. Magic armor must be donned, a Shield strapped to the arm, a cloak fastened about the shoulders. A weapon must be held.

Now admittedly this is actually a subsection of the section on magic items, which is why the text specifically refers to magic items. However, I think it also serves as reasonable guidance to apply to mundane items as well.
Returning to our one-handed question
With the above in mind, we can now return to our tricky question: can an artificer use True Strike with a one handed weapon without using their second hand at all? Here is where DM adjudication must fill in gaps in the rules. The first thing the DM needs to decide is whether the artificer can hold both objects in one hand. For example, if the artificer starts their turn holding their focus, can they draw or pick up their weapon with the same hand? In general I would say yes to this: if they can hold both items while casting a spell, there's no reason they shouldn't be able to hold them without casting a spell. I don't think it would be fair to rule otherwise, since it would basically be disallowing the spell on a technicality. It would be like saying "yes, you can manipulate both material components with one hand while casting the spell, but no, you can't hold them both in order to start casting the spell in the first place."
Assuming the DM allows holding two items in one hand, the second thing they must decide is what the consequences are. I don't think there should be no consequences, or else everyone could just walk around holding multiple weapons in each hand, just in case they need a different damage type to bypass resistance or something. One way to rule this would be that neither item is considered "equipped" in this case, which would prevent the artificer from either taking the attack action or casting spells (with the exception of True Strike for the reasons described above). Given this, I think the DM has latitude to make any ruling between these two extremes of "no consequences" and "disallow using either object". For example, they could rule that while holding both a weapon and focus in one hand, weapon attacks are at disadvantage. Or they could decide that the weapon is "wielded in a way contrary to its design" and treat is as an improvised weapon. For spellcasting (again, other than True Strike and similar spells), the DM might call for a concentration roll to complete the casting.
For argument's sake, let's suppose the DM allows the artificer to hold both objects (weapon and focus), but rules that they are only considered "equipped" in this state for actions like casting True Strike that use both objects. In this case, the artificer can still make their True Strike attack as normal, but they will be prevented from making opportunity attacks, casting reaction or bonus action spells, and so on, because those actions require holding only one or the other of the two objects, not both. The artificer can use their 1 free object interaction per turn to partially mitigate this problem. If they start their turn holding both objects, they can cast True Strike and make their attack, and then use their free object interaction to either stow their focus to enable weapon attacks or stow their weapon to make enable further spellcasting. On their next turn, they must retrieve the stowed item in order to cast True Strike again, after which they will spend the rest of that round in the awkward state of holding both objects. In all, this enables the artificer to use all their bonus actions as well as half of their reactions, which is probably good enough.

As written, this answer seems to be drawing conclusions that I don't think are intended nor well-supported. In your second section, you suggest that one can make an attack with a 2-handed weapon provided their other hand is holding material component; by that logic, a cleric could hold a shield with an emblem and attack with a great sword in the other hand.

@Pyrotechnical Holy symbols have special rules. In particular, a holy symbol on a shield does not need to be held in order to use it as a spellcasting focus. It must be "borne on" the shield. I would probably rule that a shield user can't hold anything else in the hand that's wielding the shield. In any case, this answer is talking about a spellcasting focus that is held in one's hand.
